# Database connection object is not callable exception thrown with Python Django SQL Alchemy database pooling. Why?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pool

### What I'm trying to achieve

Create a database connection pool in Django. The connection pool is connected to a PostgreSQL database by using [SQLAlchemy's connection pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html) with [django-postgrespool2](https://pypi.org/project/django-postgrespool2/).

### Thrown exception

`'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object is not callable` is thrown when running the following line of code `poolConnection = dbPool.connect()`. Printing the `dbPool` object and type displays `<sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x00000171832A72B0> <class 'sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool'>`

### Code

Database helper class which creates the connection to the PostgreSQL database and creates the connection pool:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import pool
import traceback

dbPool = None

class DbPoolHelper:

    def ensurePoolCreated(self):
        global dbPool
        if dbPool != None:
            return
            
        self.createPool()

    def dbConnect(self):
        dbConnection = psycopg2.connect(user="...", password="...", dbname="...", host="...",port="...")
        return dbConnection

    def createPool(self):
        dbConnection = self.dbConnect()
        global dbPool
        dbPool = pool.QueuePool(dbConnection, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)

    def execute(self, sql, sqlParams):
        try:
            global dbPool
            self.ensurePoolCreated()
            poolConnection = dbPool.connect()
            cursor = poolConnection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, sqlParams)
            poolConnection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            poolConnection.close()
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return e
```

The code using the `DbPoolHelper` to fetch some data by using the `execute` method and giving some sql and sql params as arguments:

```
def poolTest():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM sysproductcontainers;"
    sqlParams = ()
    db = DbPoolHelper()
    result = db.execute(sql, sqlParams)
```

### Question

Why does the code throw `'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object is not callable`?

Keep in mind that I am pretty new to Python and Django. So I might be missing something obvious to some Python and/or Django developers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`QueuePool`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool.__init__) docs the first argument should be 'a callable function that returns a DB-API connection object'.

You've passed the result of the called function to the `QueuePool` object as the first argument instead of the function itself. Remove the parenthesis to solve the issue:

```py
def createPool(self):
    dbConnection = self.dbConnect
    global dbPool
    dbPool = pool.QueuePool(dbConnection, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)
```